# querying a CSV column that might contain any of the following F,M,T,S,U,X in Django

Tags: mysql, django

Before I create a separate model, I was wondering if it is possible to query such a model in Django 2.0? My model is like this:

```
 class Block(models.Model):
    kind=models.CharField()
```

where kind can hold at least one of the options F,M,T,S,U,X

I don't want to create them as boolean columns. For now, the way to go is to create another model:

```
  class BlockModel(models.Model):
    kind=models.CharField()
    block=Models.ForgienKey(Block)
```

but since the CSV list is not big nor complex, I am thinking of storing as CSV but how would I query say for Blocks at that contain F or X?

Comment: Why don't you want them created as boolean? A single value per column is one of the principles of good sql.

Comment: True @danblack except I risk changing database design should the values change overtime (reduction or addition)